# Adding Characteristic User Description to custom C++ BLE GATT Service

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed

I am trying to add some Characteristic User Descriptions to my custom BLE GATT Service, using the [mbed API](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/). My work has so far been based on [this](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_GATT_Example/) code structure. However, I would like to add names to these characteristics. There isn't much info I could find on how to do this. However, below is a comment from a forum, stating how to do it.

```
The constructor for GattCharacteristic() takes an array of GattAttribtues as an optional argument. You can populate your User-Description into a GattAttribute and pass it along to the Characteristic.
```

So far, I have this structure setting up my characteristics.

```
uint16_t newServiceUUID         = 0xA000;
uint16_t PercentageUUID         = 0xA001;
uint16_t TimeUUID               = 0xA002;
uint16_t UseProfileUUID         = 0xA003;

const static char     DEVICE_NAME[]        = "Device"; // Device name
static const uint16_t uuid16_list[]        = {0xFFF};    

static uint8_t percentageValue[10] = {0};
WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t,
        sizeof(percentageValue)> percentageChar(PercentageUUID, percentageValue);

static uint8_t timeValue[10] = {0};
ReadWriteArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t, 
        sizeof(timeValue)> timeChar(TimeUUID, timeValue);

static uint8_t UseProfileValue[10] = {0};
WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t, 
        sizeof(UseProfileValue)> UseProfileChar(UseProfileUUID, UseProfileValue);

// Set up custom service

GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {&percentageChar, &timeChar, &UseProfileChar};
GattService        newService(newServiceUUID, characteristics, sizeof(characteristics) / sizeof(GattCharacteristic *));
```

How do I add the descriptions to these 3 characteristics?

## EDIT

I now have:

```
static uint8_t percentageValue[10] = {0};
GattAttribute descr( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t, 
        sizeof(percentageValue)> percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                                                 percentageValue,
                                                 GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                                                 &descr,
                                                 1 );
```

It throws an `Error: No instance of constructor "WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<T, NUM_ELEMENTS>::WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic [with T=std::uint8_t, NUM_ELEMENTS=10U]" matches the argument list in "main.cpp"` on the "size of" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `Characteristic` class API:
https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_API/file/d494ad3e87bd/ble/GattCharacteristic.h:

```
template <typename T>
class WriteOnlyGattCharacteristic : public GattCharacteristic {
public:
    WriteOnlyGattCharacteristic<T>(const UUID     &uuid,
                                   T              *valuePtr,
                                   uint8_t        additionalProperties = BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NONE,
                                   GattAttribute *descriptors[]        = NULL,
                                   unsigned       numDescriptors       = 0) :
        GattCharacteristic(uuid, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(valuePtr), sizeof(T), sizeof(T),
                           BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_WRITE | additionalProperties, descriptors, numDescriptors) {
        /* empty */
    }
};
```

Descriptors attached to a characteristic have to be passed as fourth parameter (`GattAttribute *descriptors[]`, by default it's NULL, meaning the characteristic has no descriptor) of the `*ArrayGattCharacteristic` objects your are creating. They are [GattAttribute](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_API/file/d494ad3e87bd/ble/GattAttribute.h)s, to be created before your characteristics and passed to it upon creation.

Maybe this could work to add one descriptor (**not tested**), arrays should be used to add more (as you did for characteristics):

```
static uint8_t percentageValue[10] = {0};
GattAttribute nameDescr( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
GattAttribute *descriptors[] = {&nameDescr};
WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t,sizeof(percentageValue)> 
        percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                        percentageValue,
                        GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                        descriptors, 
                        sizeof(descriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*) );
```

Hope this helps (again ;-))

Comment: Thanks, the first line throws this error: Error: `No instance of constructor "WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<T, NUM_ELEMENTS>::WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic [with T=std::uint8_t, NUM_ELEMENTS=10U]" matches the argument list in "main.cpp"`

Comment: Try `&&descr` as it requires a pointer to array. It would be safer/nicer to declare a real array of `GattAttribute`, as you did for characteristics.

Comment: that throws the compiler error: 230 - Syntax error(s) in Assembly.

Comment: That now compiles. How do you use that structure for multiple characters without redefining the *descriptors array for each characteristic?

Comment: That's definitely another question to be asked on SO....;-) To check if your problem is solved, copy/paste the lines and just rename the variables.

Comment: OK, have done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343188/adding-characteristic-user-description-to-multiple-custom-c-ble-gatt-service