# Adding Characteristic User Description to multiple custom C++ BLE GATT Service

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed

I am trying to add some Characteristic User Descriptions to my custom BLE GATT Service, using the [mbed API](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/). My work has so far been based on [this](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_GATT_Example/) code structure. However, I would like to add names to these characteristics. There isn't much info I could find on how to do this. However, below is the code which adds the information to a characteristic.

The constructor for GattCharacteristic() takes an array of GattAttribtues as an optional argument. You can populate your User-Description into a GattAttribute and pass it along to the Characteristic. I have this structure working for one Characteristic, but am struggling to replicate it for 3 Characters. I can't replicate the whole thing 3 times, as I run it to lots of issues about arrays etc. being already defined. If I stack the descriptions up in the array, it won't be accepted by the GattArray?

```
uint16_t newServiceUUID         = 0xA000;
uint16_t PercentageUUID         = 0xA001;
uint16_t TimeUUID               = 0xA002;
uint16_t UseProfileUUID         = 0xA003;

const static char     DEVICE_NAME[]        = "Device"; // Device name
static const uint16_t uuid16_list[]        = {0xFFF};  
static uint8_t percentageValue[10] = {0};
GattAttribute nameDescr( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
GattAttribute *descriptors[] = {&nameDescr};

WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t,sizeof(percentageValue)> 
        percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                        percentageValue,
                        GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                        descriptors, 
                        sizeof(descriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*) );

GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {&percentageChar, &timeChar, &UseProfileChar};
GattService        newService(newServiceUUID, characteristics, sizeof(characteristics) / sizeof(GattCharacteristic *));
```

## EDIT

Working with the discussion below, I now have:

```
#include <string>
class MyGattArray
{

public:
    MyGattArray( const std::string& name ) : 
        attr( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)name.c_str(), (name.size()+1) )
    {
        descriptors[0] = &attr;
    }

    GattAttribute attr;
    GattAttribute *descriptors[1];
};
```

and

```
static uint8_t percentageValue[10] = {0};
MyGattArray PercentageName( "Percentage" );
GattAttribute *descriptors[] = {&(PercentageName.attr)};

WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t,sizeof(percentageValue)> 
        percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                        percentageValue,
                        GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                        descriptors, 
                        sizeof(descriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*) );
```

This builds, but does not give the characteristic a name.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not give the characteristic a name` does the characterstic have a descriptor when you connect the device? If yes, what is its content?

Comment: @jpo38 The service is created, but the characteristic only has the 0xA001 description and nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the `WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic` function execution in both situations?

Comment: It's quite tricky, as it isn't contained in a function, so I can't do a printf. What do you want me to check for?

Comment: Use the debugger and check what's different at runtime between the two solutions....

Comment: @jpo38 I don't have a debugger, I am using a dev board, so am just using printf and serial term

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93398/discussion-between-george-edwards-and-jpo38).

Comment: Please, can you confirm that (1) the descriptor was correctly added when using the code from your original post (you can read characteristic name) (2) they are not correctly added when using the code I posted below (you cannot read characteristic name). If so, I'll try to post this as a new question in SO (why the two codes are not behaving the same, because, for me, they are strictly equivalent).

Comment: @jpo38 yes that is correct! please post a link to the new question, or bring the answer onto this, as I would be really interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition of template helper class that can encapsulate the characteristic object and its descriptor. It's a bit difficult to understand if you are not familiar with templates.

```
template <typename T, unsigned NUM_ELEMENTS, template <typename T, unsigned NUM_ELEMENTS> class CharacType>
class CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper
{
public:
    CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper( const          UUID &uuid,
                                           T              valuePtr[NUM_ELEMENTS],
                                           uint8_t        additionalProperties,
                                           const std::string& characName ) : 
        name( characName )
    {
        descriptor = new GattAttribute( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)name.c_str(), name.size() ) 
        // create descriptor array
        descriptors[0] = descriptor;
        // create characteristic object:
        charac = new CharacType<T,NUM_ELEMENTS>( uuid, valuePtr, additionalProperties, descriptors, 1 );
    }

    ~CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper()
    {
        delete charac;
        delete descriptor;
    }

    CharacType<T,NUM_ELEMENTS>* charac;
    std::string name;
    GattAttribute* descriptor;
    GattAttribute *descriptors[1];
};
```

Then, you simply do:

```
CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper<uint8_t,sizeof(percentageValue),WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic> 
        percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                        percentageValue,
                        GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                        "Percentage" );

GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {percentageChar.charac};
GattService        newService(newServiceUUID, characteristics, sizeof(characteristics) / sizeof(GattCharacteristic *));
```

Comment: Ok, just working through this now, I am getting an `Error: Expression must have pointer type` on the `GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {percentageChar->charac};` line. There also seems to be something wrong with the structure of `descriptor ( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)name.c_str(), sizeof(name) ) )` as it throws an error `Error: Expected a "{" `

Comment: I have made a few other minor edits to fix some other build errors, I will post when we get it to build.

Comment: Have you updated your answer? The code currently there just throws the same errors?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer that was not working, this is a brand new one with a template class encapsulating both the caracteristic and descriptor object.

Comment: Yes, but this one throws the errors described above. I now only have this error: `Error: Expression must have pointer type in "main.cpp" on the `GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {percentageChar->charac};` line. I also have two warnings, both `Warning: Declaration of "T" hides template parameter in "main.cpp"` and `Warning: Declaration of "NUM_ELEMENTS" hides template parameter in "main.cpp"` on the template declaration

Comment: Fixed. There a was a typo with an extra unexpected parenthesis on the `descriptor` line, and `percentageChar->charac` should be `percentageChar.charac`. But if you cannot figure this out yourslef you're going to have a hard time with your C++ project....;-)

Comment: Again, it builds but doesn't display any characteristic descriptions in the service is produces. Sorry I didn't catch that bug. I am not familiar with templates so wasn't really sure what you were trying to do - although you're right - I should have got it! Is there any debugging I can do to establish why the characteristic is being generated, but without the additional properties, do you have any ideas?

Comment: No...no more idea, I have no clue what's different between my version of code and yours, for me, they are equivalent.

Comment: Georges, I modified the `CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper` class. Please giveit a new try and tell me how it goes (Let's do this in the chat room of your OP).

Comment: Finally, we got it! ;-)

Comment: You may want to thank interjay who spotted the bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33418013/3336423