# Why those two "equivalent" codes does not end up with the same behaviour?

Tags: c++, templates

[On a separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343188/adding-characteristic-user-description-to-multiple-custom-c-ble-gatt-service?noredirect=1#comment54610697_33343188), I was helping [George Edwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620733/george-edwards) to factorize some code using a [BLE API](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/).

I'm pretty sure the code I posted (using templates for factorization) is equivalent to the original one. But when George sends it to the embedded device, the behaviour is different:

***By reading the code, can someone help figuring out what's the difference between those two pieces of code*** (they appear to be completely equivalent from my point of view)?

**Version1 of the code** (with this code, BLE descriptor for the characteristic is accessible):

```
// create descriptor
GattAttribute nameDescr( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
// create descriptor array
GattAttribute *descriptors[] = {&nameDescr};
// create characteristic
WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t,sizeof(percentageValue)> 
        percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                        percentageValue,
                        GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                        descriptors, 
                        sizeof(descriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*) );
// create characteristic array
GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {&percentageChar, &timeChar, &UseProfileChar};
// create service
GattService        newService(newServiceUUID, characteristics, sizeof(characteristics) / sizeof(GattCharacteristic *));
```

**Version2 of the code** (with this code, BLE descriptor for the characteristic is **not** accessible):

```
template <typename T, unsigned NUM_ELEMENTS, template <typename T, unsigned NUM_ELEMENTS> class CharacType>
class CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper
{
public:
    CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper( const          UUID &uuid,
                                           T              valuePtr[NUM_ELEMENTS],
                                           uint8_t        additionalProperties,
                                           const std::string& name ) : 
        // create descriptor
        descriptor( BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)name.c_str(), name.size() ) 
    {
        // create descriptor array
        descriptors[0] = &descriptor;
        // create characteristic:
        charac = new CharacType<T,NUM_ELEMENTS>( uuid, valuePtr, additionalProperties, descriptors, 1 );
    }

    ~CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper()
    {
        delete charac;
    }

    CharacType<T,NUM_ELEMENTS>* charac;
    GattAttribute descriptor;
    GattAttribute *descriptors[1];
};

// create charcteristic, descriptor and descriptor array
CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper<uint8_t,sizeof(percentageValue),WriteOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic> 
        percentageChar( PercentageUUID, 
                        percentageValue,
                        GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                        "Percentage" );
// create characteristic array
GattCharacteristic *characteristics[] = {percentageChar.charac};
// create service
GattService        newService(newServiceUUID, characteristics, sizeof(characteristics) / sizeof(GattCharacteristic *));
```

[CharacteristicWithNameDescrptorHelper](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_API/file/d494ad3e87bd/ble/GattCharacteristic.h) code can be found here (if needed).

Note that the code cannot be easily debugged by the person I'm helping because it's an embedded code. So it's hard to investigate the issue in a different manner than doing a "code review".

Comment: Does `GattAttribute` make a copy of the data you pass it, or just keep the pointer? If the latter, it will point to a destructed string.

Comment: Very good point! I'll ask Georges to try that ;-)

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thanks! Please post this as an answer so that you can get the reputation you deserve ;-) You can simply pick up the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33360701/3336423 (I updated it with a string attribute to make it be persistent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `GattAttribute` does not copy the data from the pointer you pass to its constructor, but merely holds the pointer.

In the original code this was no problem because it was passed a string literal which is always valid. In the second version, you passed it a pointer to data from a `string` which was soon destructed, so the pointer became invalid.

This can be fixed by putting the string in a member stored alongside the `GattAttribute` and calling `c_str()` on the member.